# Apply function to every element of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like this (please ignore the strlen):

```
array(2) {
  ["document"]=>
    array(16) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Value1"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Value2"
      [2]=>
      string(30) "Value3"
  ...
```

And I want to call "strtoupper" for every element (Value1, Value2, etc.) on each level of the multidimensional array (document, etc.).

I tried `array_walk_recursive($array, "strtoupper");` but it doesn't work. But why, what can I do?

Comment: Note that _array_walk_recursive_ only visits leafs. If you want 'document', which is not a leaf, also to be uppercase, you will need a different approach.

Comment: Thank you, interesting! I only need leafs but I read your solution and will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `strtoupper` does **not** change the original value, but returns new value instead, you should do this:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $array, 
    // pass value by reference. 
    // Changing it will also reflect changes in original array
    function (&$value) { $value = strtoupper($value); } 
);
```

Simple [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/vOkOt).

Also this hint is described in [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#refsect1-function.array-walk-recursive-parameters), see the note on `callback` parameter description.

Comment: Thank you!! Found the "note" in the manual. I didn't read it as I am not that used to using the manual already. Will do that from now on. Thank you! My thinking was that as `array_walk_recursive` has not an `array` as return value, it's designed to change the array directly. But that was wrong apparently.

Answer (score 1):

```
function recurse(array $array): array {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $newKey = is_string($key) ? strtoupper($key) : $key;
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result[$newKey] = recurse($value);
    } elseif (is_string($value)) {
      $result[$newKey] = strtoupper($value);
    } else {
      $result[$newKey] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}

$array = [
    'document'  => [
        'Value1',
        'Value2',
        'Value3'
    ],
    'document2' => [
        'Value21',
        'Value22',
        'document2' => [ 'Value221', 222, 'Value223' ],
        23
    ]
];

$result = recurse($array);

print_r($result);
```